# Mapping all array entries into one string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a rain function for my Discord bot that rains credits on the most active players on the chat. I am using the each() statement so I can assign the amount of credits to each person in the database.

Now what I would like to have is at the end of the rain, that one message appears on chat with all the names of the winners but the only thing I am getting is that the bot displays each name separately on the chat.

How can I map all separate array entries back into one string / message like this.

Name, Name , Name , Name
 
Name, Name , Name , Name

This is the code that I am working on.

```
PLACE = args[0];
AMOUNT = args[1];
COUNT = args[2];

async function MakeSomeMagic() {
await DB.each(`SELECT * FROM Wallet WHERE GuildID = ${G.id} AND UserID NOT IN(${A.id}) ORDER BY ${PLACE} DESC LIMIT ${COUNT}`, function(err, R) {

  var Index;
  var Array = [];

  Array.push({Name: `${R.UserName}`})
  for (Index = 0; Index < Array.length; ++Index) {

    var x = parseFloat(AMOUNT).toFixed(3);
    var y = parseFloat(COUNT);
    var Calc = x / y;
    var END = R.Balance + Calc;

    DB.run(`UPDATE Wallet SET Balance = ?, Activity = '${Time}' WHERE UserID = ? AND GuildID = ?`, [END, R.UserID, G.id]);
  }
});
```

};

Answer (score 1):

> How can I map all separate array entries back into one string

You could just call `join` on the array passing a comma as the delimiter. i.e.

`var mystring = Array.join(", ")`

EDIT

```
async function MakeSomeMagic() {
    var arr= [];
    await DB.each(`SELECT * FROM Wallet WHERE GuildID = ${G.id} AND UserID NOT IN(${A.id}) ORDER BY ${PLACE} DESC LIMIT ${COUNT}`, function(err, R) {
            var Index;
            arr.push({
                Name: `${R.UserName}`
            })
            for (Index = 0; Index < arr.length; ++Index) {

                var x = parseFloat(AMOUNT).toFixed(3);
                var y = parseFloat(COUNT);
                var Calc = x / y;
                var END = R.Balance + Calc;

                DB.run(`UPDATE Wallet SET Balance = ?, Activity = '${Time}' WHERE UserID = ? AND GuildID = ?`, [END, R.UserID, G.id]);
            }

            });

            C.send(arr.join(", "));
    };
```

Just to note Array is a reserved word - you shouldn't be naming variables Array.

Comment: Hey Fraser.  I have tried Array.join(", ");  but that will just do this 
http://prntscr.com/gx6uxy`

I is not placing the names next to each other but it still places 1 string per line. I need it to be all array items on 1 line

Comment: I can't see that SS, In any case the issue is with something you are not telling us because Join used like above produces a single string with no line breaks in it - i.e. "still places 1 string per line" is not correct - there is only one string, something else is breaking it up into lines.

Comment: The code that you can see above in the code block is the only code that is grabbing the info of the database and pushes it into a Araay.  There is no more code that will interact with this. So i am not sure with what your mean "something i am not telling" ? File complete file itself is much longer yes but those are only messages and if(!..) statements. and not of importance for my question. The code seen in the code block is the only code i am working with for the array.  And i need the entries as 1 string.  Array.join() aint seem to work for me.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you then as that is what array join does- turns an array into a single string, how are you outputting the string? Where is that code? Also how are you calling MakeSomeMagic? Honestly - array.join does exactly what it is meant to...https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: I have made a hastebin for the file i am working on.  Maby it helps. https://hastebin.com/ratidovacu.js

Comment: 'C.send(`${NewArray}`)' is wrong - it should be `C.send(NewArray)` and it needs to be outside the DB.each loop. i.,e. between `});` and `};` - see my edit

Comment: I have tried to run your edits and i am still getting the same result. It is still putting every entry on a separate line http://prntscr.com/gx74i8

Comment: On the script you place on this forum page https://hastebin.com/eyupejovub.js  i am getting the error ( arr is not refined )

Comment: If there is an error how are you getting any results? In any case the arr var needs declaring outside the scope of the function - as I have in the example. As for the output - where are the commas? Something else is clearly altering the string - put console.log(arr) - what does that look like in the console? Not on separate lines is it...

Comment: This [LINK](https://hastebin.com/kilolofize.js) script you gave me is still putting all entries on a seperate line.  And this [LINK](https://hastebin.com/eyupejovub.js) is giving me the error *arr not defined*

Comment: The problem btw is fixed..   (  var Array = [];  )  needed to be above the DB call and not inside the container.